# Why am I unable to sign in anonymously as an authenticated user in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to login as an authenticated user anonymously. Here is my code:

```js
import { initializeApp } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.14.0/firebase-app.js';
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.14.0/firebase-auth.js";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "key_here",
  authDomain: "project.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "project",
  storageBucket: "project.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "id_here",
  databaseURL: "https://project-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
  appId: "app_id_here"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth();

document.getElementById("login").addEventListener("click",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
        if(user){
             //user can successfully login
        }
        else{
            console.log("Something went wrong"); 
        }
    }, (error) => console.error(error)) //Nothing  prints here
}
```

I was able to successfully log in 'til yesterday. But since this morning I keep getting the error `Something went wrong` in my console.

I didn't change anything in the code, nor in my firebase credentials. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `onAuthStateChanged` has [`error` parameter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth#onauthstatechanged) that you can use to get error description

Comment: Maybe token expired/removed?

Comment: @Justinas how do I get the error message? Can you please show it in my code?

Comment: I have never used that, but most likely `onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => ..., (error) => console.error(error))`

Comment: @Justinas I tried that but no error shows

Comment: As far as I can tell, my `user` variable is null. I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

It was so silly of me to not read the documentation page carefully, I had forgotten to execute the `signInAnonymously()` method before checking for the user's data, the complete code is as follows:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.14.0/firebase-app.js';
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged, signInAnonymously } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.14.0/firebase-auth.js";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "key_here",
  authDomain: "project.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "project",
  storageBucket: "project.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "id_here",
  databaseURL: "https://project-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
  appId: "app_id_here"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth();

document.getElementById("login").addEventListener("click",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    signInAnonymously(auth)
        .then(() => {
            onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
                if(user){
                     //user can successfully login
                }
                else{
                    console.log("Something went wrong");
                }
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
             const errorCode = error.code;
             const errorMessage = error.message;
             console.log(errorCode+": "+errorMessage);
         });
});
```